# What is this effect/filter in given images?

Tags: filters

Here are two images. What kind of filter/processing is done here?
It looks like an emboss but the bumps are smooth.

1) Original :

[image]

2) Processed :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Highlight blooming; the bright parts are bleeding into the shadows. It can be done with Photoshop's *Diffuse Glow* filter.